# scp - How to list the path of transferring files?

Tags: scp

While using [`scp`](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/comp/security/scp_man.html) recursively using `-r` option, is there a way to list the full path of the files while they are being copied, and not merely the file name?

[image]

Comment: consider using [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/documentation.html) instead of scp, since it is designed for working with directories.  Instead of `scp -r host:dir local/dir` do `rsync -avPz host:dir/ local/dir`.  This will copy your files and show you their paths as you would like.